# Ошибка при комите

Tags: android, git, android-studio

При комите(Нажимаю в верхней панели "Vcs" выбираю некоторые файлы в которых делала изменения) сразу же при открытии окна возникает следующая ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кто то сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

> Warning not all local changes may be  shown due to an error: fatal:
>   multiple stage entries for merged file ‘/src’ during executing git -c
>   core.quotepath=false status —porcelain -z —untracked-files=no —

Нашёл что то подобное [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27330446/getting-a-fatal-error-in-git-for-multiple-stage-entries) но я не хотел добавлять все свои файлы, после чего делать кометы, но рискнул, после команды git add -A 
выбило следующее:

> warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in gradlew.bat.
>   The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

Comment: Вопросы-картинки здесь не приветствуются.

Comment: вы пытались гуглить ошибку?

Comment: будет намного лучше если Вы последовательно(делаю то то, потом то то) опишите процесс в результате которого получаете ошибку и приведете текст ошибки а не фотографию

Comment: Удалите `.git/index`, а потому попробуйте выполнить действия в `idea`

Comment: @Komdosh удалить в самой папке или как то через терминал? можно чуть поподробней.

Comment: @Inkognito, в папке проекта должна лежать папка `.git` вот там можно выполнить `rm .git/index`

Comment: @Komdosh проблема не решилась(

Answer (score 1):

По поводу

> Warning not all local changes may be shown due to an error: fatal: multiple stage entries for merged file

Если у вас Windows - я предполагаю, что дело может быть в том, что на каком-то этапе вы изменили регистр символов в имени какого-нибудь файла/папки - типа типа test.txt и Test.txt. Windows считает, что имена этих файлов одинаковы.

*Думаю, что я мог бы вам помочь в интерактивном режиме. Не уверен только, можно ли тут публиковать свои контактные данные - не нарушит ли это правила. Если можно - я напишу как со мной связаться, разберемся и результат тут зафиксируем.*

А по поводу

> warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF

Ничего страшного в нем нет и коммит все равно должен происходить. Это просто сообщение о том, что в файле gradlew.bat у вас окончания строк CRLF, а в соответствии с вашими настройками (`git config core.autocrlf`) git заменит их на LF при коммите.

Comment: `Думаю, что я мог бы вам помочь в интерактивном режиме` – в принципе, никто не запрещает. Но лучше придумать неинтерактивное решение и описать его в ответе. Так вы поможете не одному человеку, а сотням. :)

Comment: Так для помощи сотням я предполагаю опубликовать решение, к которому мы прийдем. Так или иначе связаться со мной можно по этой ссылке (действут сутки): https://discord.gg/By56M